# Yii layout doesn't get applied to view

Tags: php, yii

I'm having this problem where a view is not being run through the layout on the server, but in a local instance it works just fine without any changes. There are actually two views that have this problem, 'index' view and 'update' and 'create' view. Both of these views are partially rendering another view, 'index' is partially rendering '_view' and 'update' and 'create' are partially rendering '_form'. In the controller I'm specifying what layout should be used to render the views and made sure that the layout is not being overwritten from the action that handles each view. The code in question is as follows:

index.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

_view.php

```
<div class="well">
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('naslov')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->naslov); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('category_id')); ?>:</b>
        <?php
            $cat = Category::model()->findByPk($data->category_id);
            $parent = $cat->parent()->find();
            $c = $parent->title." / ".$cat->title;
            echo CHtml::encode($c); ?>
        <br />
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('image_path')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->image_path); ?>
    <br />

</div>
```

update.php and create.php

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

_form.php

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'news-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>

// form code 

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and in the controller that extends a base controller i define which layout is to be used

```
public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

I've looked through the application.log file trying to find anything that might cause this but didn't find anything.

---

### EDITED:

Here is the controller Create action:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new News;
    if (isset($_POST['News'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['News'];
        $model->body = $_POST['News']['body'];
        $model->author = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $model->meta_description = $_POST['News']['meta_description'];
        $path = $this->upload_path;
        $image_temp = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_path');
        $new_image_ext = pathinfo($image_temp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $new_image_subpath = uniqid(rand(), true) . '.' . $new_image_ext;
        $new_image_subpath = substr($new_image_subpath, 0, 1) . '/' . substr($new_image_subpath, 1, 1) . '/' . $new_image_subpath;
        $new_image_path = $path . $new_image_subpath;
        $model->image_path = $new_image_subpath;
        if (!file_exists(dirname($new_image_path))) {
            mkdir(dirname($new_image_path), 0777, true);
        }
    }
    if ($model->save()) {

        $image_temp->saveAs($new_image_path, false);


        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

And the Update action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $this->pageTitle = "Vesti - Izmena vesti: " . $model->naslov . "";

    if (isset($_POST['News'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['News'];
        $model->body = $_POST['News']['body'];
        $model->modified_on = date("d-m-y H:m:s");
        $model->meta_description = $_POST['News']['meta_description'];

        $model->attributes = $_POST['News'];

        if ($_FILES['News']['name']['image_path'] != "") {
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_path');
            $path = $this->upload_path;
            $image_temp = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_path');
            $new_image_ext = pathinfo($image_temp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $new_image_subpath = uniqid(rand(), true) . '.' . $new_image_ext;
            $new_image_subpath = substr($new_image_subpath, 0, 1) . '/' . substr($new_image_subpath, 1, 1) . '/' . $new_image_subpath;
            $new_image_path = $path . $new_image_subpath;
            $model->image_path = $new_image_subpath;
            if (!file_exists(dirname($new_image_path))) {
                mkdir(dirname($new_image_path), 0777, true);
            }
        } else {
            unset($model->image_path);
        }

        if ($model->save()) {

            if ($_FILES['News']['name']['image_path'] != "") {
                $image_temp->saveAs($new_image_path, false);
            }

            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('update', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

And the _form view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showSEOServices() {
        $("#seo_options").slideToggle();
    }

    function slugPopulate(s, d, a) {
        if(a==1) {
            var d = $("#News_category_id").val();
        } else {
            var s = $("#News_naslov").val();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'index.php?r=news/slug',
            data: "s=" + s + "&d=" + d,
            success: function(data) {
                 $("#News_url_slug").val(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'news-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Polja sa <span class="required">*</span> su obavezna.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'naslov'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'naslov',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255, 'onChange' => "slugPopulate(this.value, '', 1);")); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'naslov'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        Top sekcija:<br>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'top_section'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        Normalna sekcija:<br>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'normal_section'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        Donja sekcija:<br>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'bottom_section'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        Boja članka u listingu:<br>
        <?php if($model->isNewRecord!='1'){ ?>  
            <input type="color" name="News[news_color]" id="News_news_color" value="<?php echo $model->news_color; ?>">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="color" name="News[news_color]" id="News_news_color" value="">
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'body'); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('ext.editMe.widgets.ExtEditMe', array(
                                            'model'=>$model,
                                            'attribute'=>'body',

        )); ?>      
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'body'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'category_id', $model->getCategoryOptions(),array('onChange' => "slugPopulate('', this.value, 2);")); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image_path'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image_path'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'image_path'); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- FOTOGRAFIJA -->
    <?php if($model->isNewRecord!='1'){ ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo CHtml::image('/resources/uploads/news/'.$model->image_path,"image",array("width"=>200, "class" => "img-thumbnail")); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- FOTOGRAFIJA END -->

     <!-- SEO opcije -->
    <button type="button" onClick="showSEOServices()" class="btn btn-labeled btn-default">
        <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> </span>Prikaži opcije za SEO
    </button>

    <div id="seo_options" class="alert alert-info" style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'url_slug'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'url_slug',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'url_slug'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'meta_title'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'meta_title',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'meta_title'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'meta_description'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'meta_description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'meta_description'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'meta_keywords'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'meta_keywords',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'meta_keywords'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SEO opcije kraj -->

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'status'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'status', $model->getStatusOptions()); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'status'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-success ladda-button" data-style="expand-right"><span class="ladda-label">Sačuvaj</span></button>

        <?php //echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Kreiraj' : 'Sačuvaj', array("class" => "btn btn-success ladda-button", "data-style" => "expand-right")); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Look, no any parameter passes in index *_view * that's because its shows all list of rows present in specific model/table, and when we click any particular id/link from that list, then primary key pass as parameter with view like: *view?id=1* .. that's simple difference. And when we click create/update it renders to form but after saving data it render to view with last updated/created id.

Comment: and possible reason might be you uploaded view but not correctly uploaded your particular controller. It may be more clear if you show here view and its controller.